# How to Export MySQL Database From Digital Ocean Managed Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, digital-ocean, database-backups

I have a MySQL database hosted on Digital Ocean Managed Database service. I lost my previous dev machine and did not push the Schema to git along with application files. I am desperate to get back the SQL Schema  in my local machine for further Development but have so far been usuccessfull. I have tried so many commands from different suggestions but they all failed.

I connect to the DB via the MySQL Shell using the command:

`mysql -u username -password-h example-test-do-user-7878789-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com -P 25060 -D example_db`

All queries are executed successfully via this shell method. When trying to Dump the Schema to my machine, I use the following command:

`mysql -u username -p -h mysql-test-do-user-4915853-0.db.ondigitalocean.com -P 25060 your_database_name \> database_file_name.sql`

But I get the error as follows: `mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'`

if I remove that part and try again, I get the error:

`mysqldump: Got error: 2003: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error")" when trying to connect`

which doesnt make sense to me. So, without further ranting; How to I achieve my intended result.

NOTE: I did try Mysql workbench, but it won't connect all together

Answer (score 1):

I can appreciate trying to achieve what you want via mysql shell. I stumbled across the same problem and for quite some tie did not find the help i needed, then I tried doing it using mysql workbench. Try it and you will find that its easier than usin the command-line approach. MySQL Workbench has a good GUI  based database miguration capability. You can migrate you Do Managed DB directly into you local mysql server or export a schema dump. If you decide to go wit this approach, just make sure you add your machine's IP as a trusted source, else you will not be able to connect.

Comment: Did you copy this from somewhere? Best to include a source link.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue too on DigitalOcean and it's because the database hostname contains special characters which confuses `mysqldump` .. it's better to save the hostname as a variable.

This is the bash function we use in [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-dump-database.txt):

```
function ss_mysqldump_user {
    command mysqldump --user="${DB_USER}" --password="${DB_PASSWORD}" --host="${DB_HOST}" --protocol=tcp --port="${DB_PORT}" --no-create-db --no-tablespaces --single-transaction --dump-date --force "$@"
}
```

Doing this prevents the hostname from being misinterpreted.

More info:

https://slickstack.io/forum/topic/mysqldump-from-managed-remote-database-server